# I have one repository with multiple projects how do I give each project it’s on repository with the existing history?

Tags: mercurial

When I started with Mercurial about a year ago I created one repository called SandBox to put all my projects in it, now about a year later I realize that wasn’t very smart choice I have 19 project in it some of them are big.  I would like to give each project its own repository also keeping the history. Is there an easy way I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, consider a project with the following structure ([in bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/hgmultiproject)):

```
$ find hgmultiproject
hgmultiproject
hgmultiproject/proj2
hgmultiproject/proj2/mysndfile
hgmultiproject/proj1
hgmultiproject/proj1/myfirstfile
hgmultiproject/proj3
hgmultiproject/proj3/mythirdfile
```

This project has this log:

```
revision:    7:6bbc26c1a34d
tag:         tip
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Aug 08 11:49:22 2012 -0300
summary:     correcting

revision:    6:32c312e7072e
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Aug 08 11:48:55 2012 -0300
summary:     Adding period

revision:    5:f332e0ecee4d
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Aug 08 11:48:39 2012 -0300
summary:     Moving to correct name

revision:    4:5850a93d80dd
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Aug 08 11:48:05 2012 -0300
summary:     More content on second file

revision:    3:0098ebd2cea5
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Aug 08 11:47:41 2012 -0300
summary:     A third file

revision:    2:096c984a8f2a
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Aug 08 11:47:09 2012 -0300
summary:     More content on 1st file

revision:    1:b9491918efcc
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Aug 08 11:46:52 2012 -0300
summary:     My second file

revision:    0:4e429ac2fee9
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Aug 08 11:46:23 2012 -0300
summary:     My first file
```

You can extract the projects using the [Convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) with the [--filemap](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--filemap) option.

How to do it? First, you should create a filemap file. In this case, the content should be:

```
rename proj1 .
exclude proj2
exclude proj3
```

The first line will move everything inside the `proj1` dir to the root of the new repository. The second line will remove the `proj2` dir from the new repository, and the third line will remove the `proj3`.

To use it, just call this way:

```
$ hg convert --filemap proj1filemap hgmultiproject/ extracted-proj1
```

Now, enter the new repo:

```
$ cd extracted-proj1/
```

It has no working copy...

```
extracted-proj1 $ ls
```

y but you just need to update:

```
extracted-proj1 $ hg update
1 updated files, 0 merged files, 0 deleted files, 0 nonresolved files
extracted-proj1 $ ls
myfirstfile
```

And the new log is...

```
extracted-proj1 $ hg log
revision:    2:eb31727c0df8
tag:         tip
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Aug 08 11:48:55 2012 -0300
summary:     Adding period

revision:    1:e701f0ad5335
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Aug 08 11:47:09 2012 -0300
summary:     More content on 1st file

revision:    0:c0b6ad18ff22
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed Aug 08 11:46:23 2012 -0300
summary:     My first file
```

You should follow these steps for each project of your repository.

Comment: Thank You, exactly what I needed. I was using Mercurial 2.1.1 which had bug so I had to to 2.2.3 after that everything worked. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Convert extension: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension

What you actually need is `--filemap`: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--filemap